# /etc/apt/sources.list Permissions?

Tags: apt, package-management, tor

I have recently started using Terminal, and I have been having lots of problems installing programs from the Ubuntu Software Center (Minecraft, TOR, Tails installer, etc.)

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I always get

> N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

I get a system error message when I boot up in relation to `deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org xenial main`

When I try to open `/etc/apt/sources.list` with various commands it seems like it's not there, unless I open it with `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, then I get a blank document

So my guess is I have accidentally removed it or something...

What do I do ?

**Just an edit in response to Duplicate flags**

The invalid file name is sorted now (it just needed removing). My problem now is adding lines to my sources list. I tried making a new file from one of the flagged duplicate threads I moved the file and made a new one with Gedit. It seemed to restore defaults and came up with 2x canonical brothers lines. And when I try to add a line nothing happens.

-Just found out when I use `sudo su` I can now add lines to my sources list

```
sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried changing the repository to the 'Main server'?
Whenever you change it and close, it will prompt you to reload. That *should* restore the defaults.

[image: repositories in Software & Updates]

If that does not work, here is a copy of mine:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial restricted universe main multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates restricted universe main multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security restricted universe main multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Comment: So I just opened up the Software and updates ,it looked like that hyperlink ,it was on main server ,I turned it off put my password in ,turn it back on and I tried to add them lines you got there ,but when I hit add it doesn't add the line.

Comment: Thats strange, have you tried checking the permissions on the file? Try `sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list; sudo echo deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted >  /etc/apt/sources.list` and then check again. My guess is that for whatever reason the file is not being written.

Comment: That command brought up"bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied"

Comment: That's the problem, it would appear that your user (and apparently root?) does not have write access. You can try using `sudo chmod 744 /etc/apt/sources.list` however its not a good sign that your root (sudo) user cannot write to that file.

Answer (score 1):

**#1 Fix for ignoring file**

Removing the file should solve the problem, and may get rid of all the notices if the directory one is simply occurring because there are invalid files within it. Thus `50unattended-upgrades` file should be removed.

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old
```

**#2 Fix for missing `/etc/apt/sources.list`**

Simply open Software & Updates via your Dash and you will see this

[image]
Select desirable mirror, then activate checkbox to enable repositories (main, universe, restricted, multiverse) in order to create new `sources.list` file

Comment: So that command seems to have worked at removing the file and **"N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension"** is gone! Thanks for that ,it was very annoying.However My software & update dash does look like yours,but the other software tab is completely blank and I cannot add anything to it.

Comment: @BradMartin You can use [Ubuntu Sources List generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) to generate new sources list, with third-party repositories feature. Which is pretty simple to use, tho